# How can I filter a dataframe by its index

Tags: python, pandas

I want to plot my dataframe to check what algorithm should i use to predict the future values, but i have some problem while doing that.

Here is my head and tail of dataframe:

[image]

**I want to plot my dataframe. For male, I wanted to plot its weight and height, and so do it for the female too, So there should be 4 graph in total.**

Ive tried to filter my df between female and male, then plot them by typing this code below:

```
#Filter between male and female
male = df.index == "Male"
female = df.index == "Female"

#Plotting my dataframe
for label in df.columns:
  plt.hist(male[label], color='blue', label='male', alpha=0.5, density=True)
  plt.hist(female[label], color='red', label='female', alpha=0.7, density=True)
  plt.legend()
  plt.title(label)
  plt.xlabel(label)
  plt.show()
```

but it doesnt seem to work, and when i check the length of the **male**, it is said that it got 9994 rows, which is not filtered since the total of the dataframe is already 9994.

if there is a better way to plot this dataframe instead of just using a histogram and my way of filtering data by its index, feel free and please correct me if there is a better way.

Comment: you should use `male = df[df.index == "Male"]`